# Cmake error when creating a new workspace in windows

Tags: ros, windows, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i creating a new workspace(in windouws)  using

```
colcon build --merge-install
```

this error happend.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (findcolcon package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
  version 5.9.5) with any of the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

i dont know why,and dont konw how to fix it.
Does someone konw how to fix it? Iwould be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368502/cmake-error-when-creating-a-new-workspace-in-windows/) by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-12-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2021-01-24**:
I have the same issue. Did you install from binaries? Which ROS2 version and patch release are you using?

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2021-01-24**:
By the way, I think this is a duplicate to [this question.](https://answers.ros.org/question/370180/cmake-error-when-compiling-ros_tutorials-packages-in-windows-10-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-patch-release-4/)

**Comment by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on 2021-01-24**:
yes,i install from binaries,foxy.
And,the patch release maybe patch release 4? I forget it.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2021-01-25**:
@Ataraxy I just fixed the issue. Check [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/370180/cmake-error-when-compiling-ros_tutorials-packages-in-windows-10-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-patch-release-4/) for my solution.

**Comment by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on 2021-01-25**:
Thx man !! i fixed it.its useful,thx a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/370180/cmake-error-when-compiling-ros_tutorials-packages-in-windows-10-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-patch-release-4/)
this question is useful

---

Originally posted by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) with karma: 53 on 2021-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0